# Determining if unsigned overflow occurs on 68000

Tags: assembly, 68000

I am working on a question for school and can't understand this part that has to do with adding two numbers and checking if unsigned overflow occurs.

In the reference I am using, it says that both of the conditional tests VC (overflow clear) and VS (overflow set) are twos complement arithmetic and use signed numbers.

From what I understand, any of the conditional tests that use signed numbers won't work with unsigned numbers. Is there a different way I should be testing for this?

Comment: Check the C (Carry) flag in the CCR (condition code register), not the signed overflow flag.  http://mrjester.hapisan.com/04_MC68/Sect06Part01/Index.html.  There should be a branch instruction that checks the C flag.

Comment: adding two unsigned numbers should have a result that is >= both of the original, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much, I read the link you gave me and it makes sense to me now. I just have one other question, in my textbook it says that the mnemonic for the C flag being set is CS(LO); I can't find any further explanation online or in the book, is there a difference between CS and LO?

Comment: No, they're just alternate names for the same thing, so you can use the one that has the right semantic meaning.  Like LOwer after a cmp or sub instruction, for an unsigned compare, or CS to check for carry-out after an addition.  x86 has a similar thing, with JAE/JBE (above-or-equal/below) and jc/jnc (jump on carry/no-carry).  And of course also a JA condition which is true on CF=0 and ZF=0.  I haven't looked at m68k for years, but I think it has conditions that check the zero flag and the carry flag, so you can do unsigned HIgher instead of just higher-or-same.

Comment: @PeterCordes Gotcha. That makes a lot of sense now. I wish the textbook we have made stuff like that more clear. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Forgot to say: If you look up the opcode or just assemble it and check the machine code with a disassembler, you'll see they both use the same opcode in the machine code.  So it's just two mnemonics for the same machine instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OV flag is only valid for numbers you want to interpret as signed integers. It is set when any calculation passes the limit of +/- MAXINT (depending on operand size). You should ignore it normally when working with unsigned numbers. On a very low level, the OV flag is set when you add two numbers of the same sign and the result has its uppermost bit changed by a calculation.

The C flag is relevant for both signed and unsigned numbers - It is set when any calculation passes the value zero.

The conditional branches of the 68k CPU are sorted in conditions valid for signed and unsigned integers, watching combinations of V and C (and Z) flags, translating them into conditions >, =, >=, <, <=. For beginners, it is sometimes a bit confusing that identical instructions with idential opcodes may have more than one name: one that expresses the flag state, and another one that expresses "what the flags mean", like `BCC` (branch if carry clear) and `BHS` (branch if higher or same). Both of these evaluate to the same opcode.

Comment: No combinations of V and C are actually used. What is used in signed comparisons is the combination of N and V (and eventually Z, for equality). N^V could be thought as the actual sign of the result, even if the word length was not enough to hold the whole signed result.

Comment: @lvd The "and" in "V and C and Z" is a list "and", not a logical AND.

Comment: `1 - 2 => -1` or `1 + (-2) => -1` is not overflow and does not set OV.  The actual condition is more complicated than whether the upper bit changed.  See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt.

Comment: @PeterCordes No one said that. "Passing the 0" sets the carry, not the V flag.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, found it misleading after your comment.

Comment: "Passing the zero" may set the `C`-flag even in signed arithmetic, but adding two negative numbers also sets the `C`-flag.